# How get array from multidimensional array by order

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have this kind of array:

```
array(2) {
[1] => array(3) {
  [3] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "3"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
      ["parent_id"] => NULL
    }
  }
  [4] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "4"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
      ["parent_id"] => NULL
    }
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "2"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
      ["parent_id"] => NULL
    }
  }
}
[2] => &array(3) {
  [15] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(2) "15"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
      ["parent_id"] => string(1) "3"
    }
  }
  [16] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(2) "16"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
      ["parent_id"] => string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  [18] => array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(3) {
      ["id"] => string(2) "18"
      ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
      ["parent_id"] => string(1) "4"
    }
  }
}
}
```

First level means depth (1 hasn't child, 2 has parent without child, etc.). Order of array items is correct. I need obtain different array in the same order (of course in dependency of level).

```
array(6) {
[3] => array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "3"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
    ["parent_id"] => NULL
  }
}
[15] => array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "15"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
    ["parent_id"] => 3
  }
}
[4] => array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "1"
    ["parent_id"] => NULL
  }
}
[18] => &array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "18"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "4"
  }
}
[2] => array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "2"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
    ["parent_id"] => NULL
  }
}
[16] => array(3) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "16"
    ["depth"] => string(1) "2"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "2"
  }
}
}
```

Comment: and you have tried, what ?

Comment: I tried everything, but I can't get it. I think that will be need use some recursion, but I don't know how. Could you advice please?

Comment: I made first array from the same like second one. First array is just because of multidimensional sorting (alphabethical, but by arbitrary parameter (these are missing for simplicity)). But return to origin array only in different order is much more complicated.

Comment: you want the combination of array[1] and array[2] ? tried array_merge ?

Comment: '+' might work just as well, too

Comment: First array is three dimensional, second is just two dimensional. It's not possible to merge it.

Comment: from your example, you have basically a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and you want b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]. `b = array_merge(a[0], a[1])` or even `b = a[0] + a[1]`

Comment: or is that about the order of the items? (in which case that seems to be about ordering the data in the array, and in which case I also must point out that your data structure is way too complex for that sort of things)

Comment: Yes order of element in second array must correspond with order of first array. This is only one reason, why I transform first array to second. First is for multilevel sorting (it works like charm), second for listing. If would be possible multilevel sorting in second array (simultaneously origin) it would be better, but I thing that is simpler transform those arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**

### First solution

**

I found solution but I do not know how make recursion from that. It works only with two levels. Third level is order badly. Variable $this->hierarchicalData contains first array.

```
$_sortedHierarchyData = array();
foreach ($this->hierarchicalData as $levelKey => $_level) {
  foreach ($_level as $itemKey => $item) {
    if (isset($this->hierarchicalData[$levelKey + 1])) {
      $_sortedHierarchyData[$item['data']['id']] = $item;
      $children = $this->searchChildrenFromLevelOfHieararchicalSortedData($item['data']['id'], $this->hierarchicalData[$levelKey + 1]);
      $_sortedHierarchyData += $children;
    }               
  }
}

function searchChildrenFromLevelOfHieararchicalSortedData($parent_id, $level)
{
  $_children = array();
  foreach ($level as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['data']['parent_id'] === $parent_id) {
      $_children[$key] = $item;
    }
  }
  return $_children;
}
```